# get next Next/Previous item in array using react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm new to react and programming in general, I have searched and only found solutions for js not react specific.

Having trouble displaying next or previous item in an array passed via props. When Next button is clicked I only see the same item in the array being returned not the next item, I understand previous will return null as displaying first item on load.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import VideoPlayer from './Video'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this._TogglePrev = this._TogglePrev.bind(this);
this._ToggleNext = this._ToggleNext.bind(this);

// app state
this.state = {
videos: [],
selectedVideo: null
 }
}

componentDidMount() {
   axios.get('http://localhost:5000/v1/video?id=287948764917205')
   .then((result)=> {
     var videos = result.data.payload
     this.setState({
       videos: videos,
       selectedVideo: videos[0]
     });
   })
 }

componentWillUnmount() {
 this.serverRequest.abort()
 }

// State transitions
  _ToggleNext() {
    console.log("something worked");
    // take a copy of our state
    const selectedVideo = this.state.selectedVideo;
    // next video
    var i = 0,
    max = selectedVideo.length;
    for (i; i < max; i += 1) {
        if (selectedVideo[i]) {
            return selectedVideo[i + 1];
        }
    }
    //set our state
    this.setState( selectedVideo );
    console.log(selectedVideo)
  }

  _TogglePrev() {
    console.log("something worked");
    var current = this.state.selectedVideo;
    var prev = current - 1;
    if (prev < 0) {
      prev = this.state.videos.length - 1;
    }
    // update our state
    this.setState({ prev });
  }

 render() {
  return (
     <div className="App" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
       <div className="controls">
         <button className="toggle toggle--prev" onClick={this._TogglePrev}>Prev</button>
         <button className="toggle toggle--next" onClick={this._ToggleNext}>Next</button>
       </div>
        <VideoPlayer video={this.state.selectedVideo} />
     </div>
  )
 }
}
```

The returned data

```
[
 {  eventId: "287948764917205"
  userName: "Jon Doe"
  videoLink: "https://"https:s3.amazonaws.com/...""
  userPhotoLink: "https://"https:s3.amazonaws.com/...""
 },
 { eventId: "287948764917205"
 userName: "Jane Thompson"
 videoLink: "https://"https:s3.amazonaws.com/...""
 userPhotoLink: "https://"https:s3.amazonaws.com/...""
 }  
]
```

Comment: there's a typo. try doing `this.setState( {selectedVideo} );` instead of `this.setState( selectedVideo )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mistakes:**

**1.** If you use `return` keyword inside `for` loop it will not **only** break the `loop`, it will return from that function also, so in these lines:

```
for (i; i < max; i += 1) {
    if (selectedVideo[i]) {
        return selectedVideo[i + 1];
    }
}
this.setState( selectedVideo );
....
```

If `if(selectedVideo[i])` will return true then it will break the loop and return from the function, so the lines after this `for` loop will never executes because of that return statement.

**2.** `setState` is a function and we need to pass an `object` (key-value pair, key will be the state variable names) in this, so you need to write it like this:

```
this.setState({ selectedVideo }); or this.setState({ selectedVideo: selectedVideo });  //both are same
```

**Another way** of writing the code by maintaining index:

**1.** Instead of maintaining `selectedVideo` in state variable maintain the index only, index of item of the array.

**2.** On click of next and prev button, increase or decrease the value of index and use that index to pass specific object of the state videos array to child component.

Like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import VideoPlayer from './Video'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            videos: [],
            selectedIndex: 0
        }
        this._TogglePrev = this._TogglePrev.bind(this);
        this._ToggleNext = this._ToggleNext.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/v1/video?id=287948764917205')
        .then((result)=> {
            var videos = result.data.payload
            this.setState({
                videos: videos,
                selectedIndex: 0
            });
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.serverRequest.abort()
    }

    _ToggleNext() {
        if(this.state.selectedIndex == this.state.videos.length - 1)
            return;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            selectedIndex: prevState.selectedIndex + 1
        }))
    }

    _TogglePrev() {
        if(this.state.selectedIndex == 0)
         return;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            selectedIndex: prevState.selectedIndex - 1
        }))
    }

    render() {
        let {selectedIndex, videos} = this.state;
        return (
             <div className="App" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                  <div className="controls">
                    <button className="toggle toggle--prev" onClick={this._TogglePrev}>Prev</button>
                    <button className="toggle toggle--next" onClick={this._ToggleNext}>Next</button>
                  </div>
                  <VideoPlayer video={videos[selectedIndex]} />
             </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, helped me understand react more

Comment: glad, it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.activeElement` in order to get the currently focused element. Then, use `nextElementSibling` on order to get the next element then `focus()`  just like this`document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.focus()`

- **Full example**:

```
export default function TextField() {
    return (
        <div
        onKeyDown={(e:any)=>{
            if (e.keyCode==13){
                const active:any = document.activeElement
                active.nextElementSibling.focus()
            }
        }}
        >
            <input/>
            <input/>
            <input/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better  to write  in the constructor:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._TogglePrev.bind(this);
    this._ToggleNext.bind(this);

    // app state
    this.state = {
    videos: [],
    selectedVideo: null,
selectedVideoIndex:0
     }
    }
```

and also change

```
 _ToggleNext() {
    console.log("something worked");
    // take a copy of our state
    const selectedVideo = this.state.selectedVideo;
    // next video
    var selectedVideoIndex = this.state.selectedVideoIndex; //i always starts with zero ????? you need also to save the index

    max = selectedVideo.length;
    for (selectedVideoIndex; selectedVideoIndex < max; selectedVideoIndex++) {
        if (selectedVideo[selectedVideoIndex]) {
            const retval = selectedVideo[selectedVideoIndex + 1];
            this.setState( selectedVideoIndex+1 );
            this.setState(retval  );
            return retval;
        }
    }


    console.log(selectedVideo)
  }
```